# Is this sign in a Mongolian airport saying you can dispose of toilet paper in the bin?

Tags: hygiene, mongolia, mongolian-language

At this toilet at Chiingis Khaan airport (ULN) in Ulaanbaatar, which had a bin for toilet paper, there was a sign appearing to say that it's ok to either use the toilet, or the rubbish bin, for disposing of toilet paper. There's text in Mongolian, but not English. The concept of someone voluntarily choosing to use a bin seems surprising, though I understand people doing so to avoid damaging the plumbing in several countries. Did I interpret the sign correctly?

[image]

Comment: Disposing of used toilet paper in a bin next to the WC is standard in many countries, e.g. China, as plumbing is not able to cope with the paper. Why would this seem surprising? Many humans would find it surprising to dispose of the paper into the WC.

Comment: It's common in Greece too.

Comment: countries where you can put paper in the toilet are sadly the exception rather than the norm I'd go as far to say

Comment: @Tom So, you're asking Andrew to go take some photographs in the toilets? Er.... ;-)

Comment: it's common in Vietnam too

Comment: Flushing or not flushing toilet paper is not due to some quaint facet of local culture, it's due to what the plumbing can handle. Retagging accordingly.

Comment: @hippietrail But whether plumbing that can handle it is typically installed presumably is primarily a function of local culture.

Comment: @reirab: Nope, it's due to development, finances, technology, existing infrastructure, political priorities, etc. Culture is stuff like language, religion, etc.

Comment: @hippietrail Ah, well, I guess we're using different definitions of culture, then. I would include most or all of those things in culture.

Comment: I think there's a huge difference. It makes "culture" too broad. It should be for things that would be in a course on a culture or that you'd see at a cultural centre or the traits of ethnic diversity that the word "multicultural" refers to. In any case I don't think "plumbing culture" is remotely a travel topic whereas whether to flush or bin TP is. I don't think anybody would say "In my *culture* we put the paper in the bin." but would say "In my *country* we can't flush the paper because the plumbing sucks". I think it's even rude to lump such a thing in with questions about culture.

Comment: Anyway maybe a meta question on question on english.SE might be interesting? In the meantime here's some interesting relevant stuff I found on quora: [1](https://www.quora.com/What-cultural-background-people-prefer-collecting-used-toilet-paper-in-a-bin-next-to-the-toilet-instead-of-flushing-the-used-paper/answer/Joachim-Pense?srid=o6eA), [2](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-not-flush-down-toilet-paper-in-China/answer/Guo-Wei-6?srid=o6eA)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No; this sign means you have to use bin for disposing of toilet paper. I used Google translator to translate the text on signs:

- 2nd sign means "Don't forget to flush".
- 3rd sign means "Use trash bin for toilet paper and napkins".

*It's strange that an international airport does not double text on signs in English.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44999/discussion-on-answer-by-neusser-is-this-sign-in-a-mongolian-airport-saying-you-c).